# How do you pipe shell output to ruby -e?

Tags: ruby

Say I was typing something in my terminal like:

```
ls | grep phrase
```

and after doing so I realize I want to delete all these files.

I want to use Ruby to do so, but can't quite figure out what to pass into it.

```
ls | grep phrase | ruby -e "what do I put in here to go through each line by line?"
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete the files with Ruby?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this as a starting point:

```
ls ~ | ruby -ne 'print $_ if $_[/^D/]'
```

Which returns:

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
```

The `-n` flag means "loop over all incoming lines" and stores them in the "default" variable `$_`. We don't see that variable used much, partly as a knee-jerk reaction to Perl's overuse of it, but it has its useful moments in Rubydom.

These are the commonly used flags:

```
-e 'command'    one line of script. Several -e's allowed. Omit [programfile]
-n              assume 'while gets(); ... end' loop around your script
-p              assume loop like -n but print line also like sed
```

Comment: This command doesn't work in Ruby 2.0 apparently. Pasted it exactly and I get ```bad math expression: operand expected at `/^D/'```

Comment: Well, on my systems, using Ruby 2.0 it works fine. It's not Ruby code though, it's to be pasted at the shell prompt. Did you do that?

Comment: Maybe I skipped a char or something. I tried again and it works now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Protip: `$_` is implicitly passed to `print` and pattern matching, so you could even just use `ls ~ | ruby -ne 'print if /^D/'`

Answer (score 5):

`ARGF` will save your bacon.

```
ls | grep phrase | ruby -e "ARGF.read.each_line { |file| puts file }"
=> phrase_file
   file_phrase
   stuff_in_front_of_phrase
   phrase_stuff_behind
```

`ARGF` is an array that stores whatever you passed into your (in this case command-line) script.
You can read more about `ARGF` here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html

For more uses check out this talk on Ruby Forum:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/85528

Comment: What if it's a continuous stream of data?